# Как разбить видеофайл на несколько по размеру файла при помощи FFMPEG?

Tags: windows, видео, ffmpeg, конвертация

Как разбить большой видеофайл на несколько видеофайлов по 2 ГБ при помощи FFmpeg?

Comment: FFmpeg не знает заранее, как большой будет итоговой (закодированный) файл.

Comment: @MarianD а заранее и не надо, достаточно проверять итоговый размер в процессе записи, набралось два гига — закрываем текущий файл, создаём следующий файл

Comment: Собственно для этого даже есть опция `-fs`, но к сожалению она только закрывает текущий файл, а следующий файл не создаёт (странно что segment format умеет делить по времени, но не по размеру)

Comment: @andreymal: *«странно что segment format умеет делить по времени, но не по размеру»* - это не странно, а необходимо - FFmpeg знает точно час каждой входной снимки (PTS - Presentation Time Stamp), но не знает, какое количество байтов она будет оккупировать после ее перевода (перекодирования) на фрейм.

Comment: @MarianD segment format работает с уже закодированными фреймами и с конкретным видеоконтейнером, поэтому он способен точно посчитать занимаемое число байт

Comment: @andreymal, вы прав, я ошибся. Но все таки остается вопрос, сколько байтов будет нужно для этих точно знакомых байтов (пакетов в памяти) на диске.